# play mp4 in background on website

Tags: mp4

I am making a auction website in php.
I want to add music in background when auction is going to be ended .
I cant understand how?
Please help

Comment: It might be a valid use case. Little 'notification' sounds are used by heaps of websites.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to MP3, you can then use jQuery Sound plugin to play it via Flash.